# Не могу залезть внутрь кода HTML (Python Parser bs4, requests)

Tags: python, html, парсер, requests, bs4

```
import requests # Запросы
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # Чтение
import csv

HOST = 'https://spa.profticket.ru/'
URL = 'https://spa.profticket.ru/customer/53/shows'
HEADERS = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 YaBrowser/20.12.3.138 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36'
}

def get_html(url, params=''):
    session = requests.Session()  # Строчка нужна, для того, чтобы сайт думал, что зашел 1 пользователь
    r = session.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params) # Запрос на страницу
    return r # Возврат полученной страницы

def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', id='app')
    cards = []
    print(items)

html = get_html(URL)
get_content(html.text)
```

Вывод:

```
C:\Users\Fallervood\PycharmProjects\theaterParsing\venv\Scripts\python.exe
C:/Users/Fallervood/PycharmProjects/theaterParsing/main.py
[<div id="app"></div>]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Проблема в том, что не могу пролезть дальше вот этого `div`'a, а почему - не понятно.

Comment: Какой ожидаемый результат?

Comment: @МихаилМуругов хочу взять div из div id = 'app' но дальше не могу пролезть